# Android setUnselectedAlpha() does not reset to full opacity on selected item in Gallery view

Tags: android

As the title says, if I use **setUnselectedAlpha()** on my gallery, the selected items never return to full opacity.  I found some of the same questions online and the only answer I found was that it had to be using a style to have the **setUnselectedAlpha()** work properly.  I hope this is not the case because I don't want a background or border in my gallery.  Anyway I tried that solution and it is still not working.  Has anyone ran into this before and is there a solution?

Thank you!

Comment: Had the same issue. Alpha was set correctly at startup, but as soon as the tab was selected once, it didnt set the correct alpha. The only chance I had was to not use different alpha...

Comment: I'll tell you what, after two weeks of trying to dev in Android I'm pretty turned off by all the road blocks.  Its like they've tried to make creating anything customizable as hard as possible.  Pretty unimpressed so far.  :(  Well if I find anything on this I'll make sure to let you know!

Answer (score 2):

Works fine when u add this, to your gallery:

**style="android:galleryItemBackground"**

so the code:

```
   <Gallery style="android:galleryItemBackground"
    android:id="@+id/gallery"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:layout_gravity="top" android:layout_marginTop="50dip"/>
```

and then

```
g.setUnselectedAlpha(0.3f);
```

then on getview:

```
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
    ImageView i = new ImageView(mContext);

    position= getPosition(position); 

    i.setImageBitmap(images.elementAt(position));
    i.setScaleType(ImageView.ScaleType.FIT_CENTER);

    i.setBackgroundColor(R.color.chatblue); //add some background, and it work! 


    return i;
}
```